# how to use script to conditionally modify values in CSV file

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

The CSV file contains name and Values

i want any value more than 1000 converted to 1000 in same file or in differentt file. mostly using shell script. what is the best way to it?

for example the values are as follows

```
Name Value
ABV 1200
CCD 1000
CAD 500
DDD 1800
```

and i want it as

```
Name Value
ABV 1000
CCD 1000
CAD 500
DDD 1000
```

i tried awk function but it didnt work any other alteernatives

Comment: Not my downvote but as this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some
attempt first. Don't post it as a comment, an image, a table or a link
to an off-site service but use text and include it to your original
question. Thanks.

Comment: i tried using awk command  awk -F, '{if ($2 -gt 1000) {$2=1000} {print $0}}' book1.csv > book2.csv. bu it is modifing all cells in 2nd row. which i dont want. thats why i was searching any other alternatives

Comment: @ICHIGO1699, kindly do add your shown efforts into your question, which us encouraged else you may get close votes on your question, thank you. Not my close vote BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{print $1,($2+0>1000?1000:$2)}' file
```

Output:

```
Name Value
ABV 1000
CCD 1000
CAD 500
DDD 1000
```

Comment: i had to add -F to the command above and now it works... Thnak you So MUch

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with OP's current code:

- need to skip processing of the first line
- `-gt` is invalid in `awk` ... use `>` instead
- `-F,` says to use the comma as the input field delimiter but the sample input file does not contain commas; for now I'm going to assume the sample input file is correct (ie, there are no commas)

Updating OP's current code to address these issues:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0; next} {if ($2 > 1000) {$2=1000} {print $0}}' book1.csv
```

Or an equivalent:

```
awk 'NR>1 && ($2>1000) {$2=1000} 1' book1.csv
```

Both of these generate:

```
Name Value
ABV 1000
CCD 1000
CAD 500
DDD 1000
```